# Из xml корректно изъять несколько одинаковых тегов подряд из одного родительского элемента

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, парсер

Есть файл(упрощенный вариант):

```
<items>
    <item>
        <issue>
            <number>4</number>
            <number>22</number>
        </issue>
    </item>
    <item>
        <issue>
            <number>4</number>
        </issue>
    </item>
    <item>
        <issue>
            <number>11</number>
            <number>1</number>
        </issue>
    </item>
    <item>
        <issue>
            <number>6-2</number>
        </issue>
    </item>
    <item>
        <issue>
            <number>11-2</number>
            <number>63</number>
        </issue>
    </item>
    <item>
        <issue>
            <number>1-12</number>
            <number>6</number>
        </issue>
    </item>
    <item>
        <issue>
            <volume>11</volume>
            <number>6</number>
        </issue>
    </item>
    <item>
        <issue>
            <number>5</number>
            <number>612</number>
        </issue>
    </item>
</items>
```

Когда я извлекаю номера, они "склеиваются" и не понятно, то ли это 4 номер и 22 выпуск, то ли 42 номер и 2 выпуск + еще есть Том выпуска (тег `<volume>`) + номера, в которых есть "-" его заменить нужно на ", ч. "(это я сообразила, как сделать). Я решила посчитать количество цифр, но запись местами встает некорректно

Мой вариант:

```
sd = len(number)
if sd == 3:
    number[0] + ' ' + '(' + number[1] + number[2] + ')'
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы все встало корректно:

```
4 (22)
4
11 (1)
6, ч. 2
11, ч. 2 (63)
1, ч. 12 (6)
Т. 11 N 6
5 (612)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как этого можно достичь? Заранее благодарна за ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import io
from lxml import etree

#xml = """XML текст"""

tree = etree.parse(io.StringIO(xml))

def find_num(item):
    res = ""
    vol = item.xpath("issue/volume")
    if vol:
        res = f"Т. {vol[0].text} N "
    num_cnt = 0
    for i in item.xpath("issue/number"):
        num = i.text.replace('-', ', ч. ')
        if num_cnt > 0:
            res += f" ({num})"
        else:
            res += num
        num_cnt += 1
    return res
```

использование:

```
In [39]: for item in tree.xpath("//item"):
    ...:     print(find_num(item))
    ...:
4 (22)
4
11 (1)
6, ч. 2
11, ч. 2 (63)
1, ч. 12 (6)
Т. 11 N 6
5 (612)
```

Comment: благодарю Вас за ответ. У меня почему-то выходит ошибка "Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.". Я перевела данный текст, но, если честно, не поняла, где мне нужно поправить код

Comment: @Ireen1985, какая строка кода выдаёт ошибку?

Comment: Ошибка выходит на первой строке "tree = etree.parse(io.StringIO(xml))"

Comment: @Ireen1985, вы можете выложить часть данных, которые позволят воспроизвести ошибку?

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо, что откликнулись на мой вопрос. Я сама поковырялась и нашла решение, скорее всего, оно корявое, но работает